# '-' changed to '_' while converting xml to hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, hash, special-characters

**xml = `"<outer-tag><inner-tag>value</inner-tag></outer-tag>"`**

**hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)**  ==> this gives me the following output

**{"outer_tag"=>{"inner_tag"=>"value"}}**

I actually need **hash = {"outer-tag"=>{"inner-tag"=>"value"}}**

Is there any way to convert XML to Hash without changing "-" to "_" ?

Comment: As I Dig down the Rails Source code I think it's not possible It calls the normalize_key method of XMLConverter which replaces '-' to '_' . 
May be any one else can shed a light on some global configuration to prevent that

Comment: Apparently you can replace '-' with some sentinel value and replace it back to '-' after conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let check [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/14e92bac1a4c199e5e8936c6bdc64420293ea6d1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb) at line 164. Rails normalizes the hash keys from `-` to `_`

So, I come up with 2 solutions:

1. Call rails private method

   ```
   xml = "<outer-tag><inner-tag>value</inner-tag></outer-tag>"
   hash = ActiveSupport::XmlMini.parse(xml)
   result = ActiveSupport::XMLConverter.new("").send(:deep_to_h, hash)
   ```

This is **risky** since rails may have an internal changes and we are in error-prone

2. Convert key from `_` back to `-`

   ```
   xml = "<outer-tag><inner-tag>value</inner-tag></outer-tag>"
   hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
   normalize_keys = -> (params) do
     case params
       when Hash
         Hash[params.map { |k,v| [k.to_s.tr('_', '-'), normalize_keys.call(v)] } ]
       when Array
         params.map { |v| normalize_keys.call(v) }
       else
         params
     end
   end
   result = normalize_keys.call(hash)
   ```

This is better, but too much longer, just my idea, welcome any comment!